# Prove $\left \langle n_{1}, n_{2},...,n_{k} \right \rangle =\left\langle (n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{k})\right \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that in $\mathbb{Z}$, $\left \langle n_{1}, n_{2},...,n_{k} \right \rangle =\left\langle (n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{k})\right \rangle$.

If somebody could explain to me what exactly the problem is asking. Is it talking about the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: it might help to explain what your notaton means...

Comment: Im assuming that given a group $\mathbb{Z}$, if $n_{1}, n_{2},...,n_{k}\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: then $\left \langle n_{1}, n_{2},...,n_{k} \right \rangle$ is a cyclic group

Answer (score 3):

Probably $\langle n_1,\dots,n_k\rangle$ denotes the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $n_1,\dots,n_k$, or in other words the set of all sums $x_1 n_1 + \cdots + x_k n_k$, where $x_1,\dots,x_k\in\mathbb{Z}$, while $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $n_1,\dots,n_k$, often denoted $\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ (or $\text{hcf}(n_1,\dots,n_k)$) precisely in order to avoid confusion of this sort, so $\langle(n_1,\dots,n_k)\rangle$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the single element $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$, or the set of all multiplies of $(n_1,\dots,n_k)$.

Comment: To *solve* the problem, I recommend first thinking about $k=2$. It may remind you of a result that you have probably seen before.

Comment: where should I start in proving this equality?

Comment: @Dome Can you prove either $\subset$ or $\supset$?

Comment: let k=2, then we need to show that $\left \langle n_{1}, n_{2}\right \rangle=\left \langle (n_{1}, n_{2})\right \rangle$ Im thinking $\left \langle 6,8 \right \rangle = \left \langle 2\right \rangle$  which is the set of all even integers? but where do I go from here?

Comment: Can you prove that $\langle n_1,n_2\rangle$ is contained in $\langle(n_1,n_2)\rangle$?

Comment: Umm, not exactly... :(

Comment: Where would i have to start?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10551/discussion-between-sean-eberhard-and-dome)